# Asynchronously add controls to Form during Form_Load

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm working on a utility to copy a directory to multiple USB sticks. When Form1 loads, I would like for a label to display status "Detecting Disk Drives...", and then call a method to read the drives and populate the form with information. I have it working, except when the form loads it calls the method before displaying the label. Therefore it appears to be hung (the label is actually a white box on a gray background). I have tried timers and threads and everything I can think of, each with a different dead end. I have not yet found a way to have the label update before calling the method to read the drives.

The method getAndDisplayData() is wait 'hangs' my program. I would like for it not to be called until after the form has updated the text of lblDisplayStatus.Text

I also do not want the user to have to interact with the form before calling the method.

Here is my C# code:

```
    private void USB_Utility_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblDisplayStatus.Text = "Detecting Disk Drives...";
    }

    private void tabUSB_Prep_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tabUSB_Prep.Controls.Clear();
        getAndDisplayData();
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code that I ended up with:

```
    BackgroundWorker _worker;

    private void USB_Utility_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _worker = new BackgroundWorker(); // Should be a field on the form.
        _worker.DoWork += DoWork;
        _worker.RunWorkerCompleted += RunWorkerCompleted;
        lblDisplayStatus.Text = "Detecting Disk Drives...";
        _worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    //Background Worker
    private void RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        lblDisplayStatus.Text = "Done...";
        displayData();
    }

    private void DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        getData();
    }
```

Comment: A BackgroundWorker should work fine here. When you say you tried everything, including threads, I'm inclined to not believe you or you messed up and still did all the work on the UI thread.

Comment: It doesn't just *look* hung, it actually *is* hung.  Add lblDisplayStatus.Update() to hide that.  Never use Controls.Clear(), disposing controls is not optional.

Comment: The problem I had with using a thread was that the "Display" part of the method I am calling throws an exception for a "Cross thread operation not valid" when I try to add a control to the form.

Comment: Each of the options below would probably have worked, however in my code I was trying adding controls in the called method, which cannot be done in this other thread. To fix my issue I have used the BackgroundWorker and passed the data back to the main thread to create the controls and add them to the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The old-fashioned way would be to use a `BackgroundWorker` to run the blocking work in `getAndDisplayData` and then update the label before starting the worker and again when the worker completes.

Now-adays I assume you could also use tasks to get the exact same result, but I haven't actually tried it as WinForms is not often first choice for new projects.

```
   BackgroundWorker _worker;

   public void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
       _worker = new BackgroundWorker(); // Should be a field on the form.
       _worker.DoWork += DoWork;
       _worker.RunWorkerCompleted += RunWorkerCompleted;
       lblDisplayStatus.Text = "Detecting Disk Drives...";
       _worker.RunWorkerAsync();
   }

   private void RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)   {
     lblDisplayStatus.Text = "Done...";       
    }

   private void DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) {
       getAndDisplayData();
   }
```

[About background workers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx)

Comment: Inside of the getAndDisplayData method I have the following command tabUSB_Prep.Controls.Add(statusLabel); when this is called i get the following exception: An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'tabUSB_Prep' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on. I get the same exception when trying threads.

Comment: @d3v1l6oy Create and maintain your controls in the `DoWork` section, pass it to the `RunWorkerCompleted` and try adding it from there. Then you should be able to.

Comment: @sab669 Thank you, this was were my real problem was. Everything is working as I would expect it to.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the new(ish) async/await pattern, you need to use the [TaskScheduler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.aspx) to update the UI from the original thread. Here's an example:

```
// clear the form
tabUSB_Prep.Controls.Clear();

// This is just to show crossing a "context" works
string test = "";

// get the UI's current TaskScheduler
var scheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();

// This can be used to wrap a method that doesn't 
// directly implement async/await  
Task.Run(() =>
{  
    // Your method to GET the data (don't update the UI here)

    test = "I can set a variable in this context!";

}).ContinueWith(task =>
{
    if (task.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
    {
        // update your UI here

        // Again, this is just to show how crossing the context works
        MessageBox.Show(test);
    }
    else
    {
        // update UI with an error message, or display a MessageBox?
    }
}, scheduler);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
 private void USB_Utility_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblDisplayStatus.Text = "Detecting Disk Drives...";
}

private void tabUSB_Prep_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tabUSB_Prep.Controls.Clear();
    Task<List<string>> t = new Task<List<string>>(DetectDrivesMethod());
                    t.ContinueWith((result)=>DisplayDrives(result.Result),TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext);
                    t.Start();
}
```

You can tweak the code to fit your requirement. In DetectDriveMethod you will have logic to get data in background thread and in continue with, you can have logic to update UI. It is important that you pass syncronization context otherwise you will end up with Cross Thread exceptions.